# Cam seal replacement part number

Tags: subaru, camshaft, seal, legacy

My Subaru legacy is a 2017 model with timing chains instead of belts. I cannot find the part number online for the little seal that goes behind the timing sprockets. Does anyone know the part number for the seals?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair? What engine does your Legacy have in it? Could be an H4 or H6. And I take it the car isn't an STi or WRX model? (I don't even know if the Legacy came with these options ... just making sure.) Also, I'll be changing the wording of your question just a little so as it is on topic for the site.

Comment: the engine is 2.5L H4 SOHC 16V. I cannot find the part number for the life of me. @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2

Comment: I'm wondering if it's called a "Timing Cover Seal". If so, the part number would be MAHLE 68015 or SKF 19673A (manufacturer name followed by number).

Comment: it is not a gasket for the timing cover. it is a gasket that sits behind the cam sprocket and in front of the cam shaft. some timing cover gaskets kits sell these gaskets alongside the one you are talking about.

Comment: What I was showing is a seal, which would go on a shaft. Don't get hung up on what the title is, but rather what it is and does. If you think about it, this would seal the camshaft where it comes through the cover to protect the area forward which would be the timing cover area. I'm thinking your best bet may be to go to a Subaru dealer and look on their screens so you can point out what you need, then get the part number from them. You wouldn't have to buy their part, but they would have the part number.

Comment: they do look like the right ones. I don't know why I cant find them as oem parts though.